# how to register multiple test user on oovvoo for video call

Tags: android, authentication, chat, call, videochat

I have downloaded sdk of oovvoo from here https://github.com/oovoodev/Android-SDK-Sample and integrated video calling successfully.I register app on oovvoo's website and get app-id and token for this.

The problem is I am not getting oovvoo sign up page, so not able to chose user for video call. In this situation all the users adding in the conference. I need a way to implement manage user and user selection for video calling. I have seen- call.http://support.oovoo.com/link/portal/3908/4244/Article/1291/Quick-Start-Guide-for-Android but there is no implementation guidance for developers. Do we need to handle users on our end by the user-id or oovvoo providing this feature on its any sample.

i tried "oovoosdk-android-2.0.0.67" also but still have same issue.

Can any one please tell me how to register multiple test user on oovvoo for video call for a single application. 
Please help.

Comment: It will be great if any one know the solution so answer it rather then down vote it. It can help me.

Comment: https://github.com/oovoodev/Android-SDK-Sample here is sample code given, you don't need to regsiter any user on ooVoo, understand this sdk flow, it's simple

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the reply from oovvoo support team. For Now they don't have user management section in provided SDK. They send this- "ooVoo SDK doesn't provide today user identity management.
we are going to release in one month chat and signaling functionality and where you will be able to provide user ID and the user will join a call."

Comment: Hello, as of December 06, 2016 I'm facing the exact same problem. I can add a user and call it, but what if I don't know user id?

I'd like to make a popup in my Android application whit a list of connected users so I can select one and make a video call.

Anyone knows how to do this?